# "Circling" a Kos Shel Bracha?

Tags: minhag, wedding

I just saw *Fiddler on the Roof in Yiddish* off-Broadway last night. In the wedding scene, the rabbi holds the *Kos Shel Bracha* from underneath but then kind of "orbits" the cup -- rotating his hand in circles parallel to the ground -- as if to mirror the circling of the kallah around the chosn. Is this "circling" a known *minhag*? Found in a *sefer* somewhere? Or was this just some brilliant theatrical direction?

Comment: The Gemara in Berakhot recommends עיטור of a kos shel bracha which some think means encircling the kos with other cups. Somewhat similar

Comment: Thank you. https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.51a.16?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi